# How 301 Redirect any URL that has a certain variable?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an old site to clean up that has many pages with this ugly url format:

```
/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=47&Itemid=63
```

How do I write a rule in the **.htaccess** file that redirects any url that starts with `?option=` to root `/`

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with rewrite rules, if you can also patch it in the `index.php` file itself which presumably still exists within the new site?

```
if(!empty($_GET['option']))
{
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header('Location: http://my.domain.tld/');
  die;
}
```

This also correctly catches URLs that historically existed but had parameters switched or prefixed so that `option` wasn't at the beginning, and allows you to more flexibly patch if one day you need to use an `option` GET-parameter again.

Mod_rewrite is cool, but not the solution to every redirection problem.

Having said that, if you truly insist on the `.htaccess` solution, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=(.*)
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

It tests the query string and then redirects all requests if it matches.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I should have specified that I need the code for the .htaccess file.

Comment: You did, and I told you it's probably a sub-optimal solution compared to a patch to `index.php`. Why is that not possible and do you insist on a `.htaccess` solution?

Comment: I'm using Wordpress for this site, So I would prefer to put the redirects in the .htaccess and keep it separate from the template theme & files as I'm no expert.

Comment: The index.php isn't part of the template file and themes, will also be accidentally overwritten during upgrades, and debugging .htaccess is harder than PHP - but I've already edited the mod_rewrite version in.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. I've gone with your recommendation. Thanks!